# Priority Queue using min heap with ability to remove any node at O(log(n)) [ vector approach ]

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, heap, priority-queue

Feel free to point out my mistakes, I do not claim to be a good C++ programmer or even good w/ Data structures. I'm just looking to improve and learn upon my example.

This approach is not my own but the code is. I learned a concept and attempted to code it in C++.

The point here is to learn to build this without using libraries such as std::priority_queue. Thanks again!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>



// directions of each node
enum
{
    IS_LEFT = 1,
    IS_RIGHT = 2
};



// (ADT) Priority Queue which uses a (DS) heap
using std::vector;



// Makes removal of any node anywhere within the heap O(log(n))
using std::unordered_map;



class BinaryStack
{
private:
    
    // tracks the last node in heap
    size_t last_index { 0 };
    
    
    
    // the heap
    vector<int> heap{ };
    
    
    
    // the hashmap to track where any given node is at (required for node removal within a heap)
    unordered_map<int, vector<size_t>> hashmap{ };
    
    
    
    // swap any two values from two given vectors
    void swapVectorValue(vector<size_t> &vec1, size_t val1, vector<size_t> &vec2, size_t val2)
    {
        vec1.erase(std::remove(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), val1), vec1.end());
        vec2.erase(std::remove(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), val2), vec2.end());
        vec1.push_back(val2);
        vec2.push_back(val1);
    }
    
    
    
    // adds a value to hashmap | the keys are the node values & the values are their respective indexes
    void addToHashMap(int val, size_t last_index)
    {
        auto search = hashmap.find(val);
        if (search != hashmap.end())
            hashmap[val].push_back(last_index);
        else
            hashmap[val] = vector<size_t> { last_index };
    }
    
  
    
    
public:
    
    // insert a node into the heap
    void insert(int val)
    {
        heap.push_back(val);
      
        // point last node to end of array
        size_t last_index = heap.size()-1;
       
        addToHashMap(val, last_index);
        
        // only one node so lets just stop here
        if (heap.size() == 1) return;
        
        // determines if node is on left or right
        short node_direction = (heap.size() % 2 == 0) ? IS_LEFT : IS_RIGHT;
        
        size_t parent_index = (last_index - node_direction) / 2;
        
        // keep going until bubbles to top
        while (heap[parent_index] > heap[last_index])
        {
            //swaps indexes of swapped nodes
            swapVectorValue(hashmap[heap[parent_index]], parent_index, hashmap[heap[last_index]], last_index);
            
            // update value of parent and new node
            int temp { heap[parent_index] };
            heap[parent_index] = heap[last_index];
            heap[last_index] = temp;
            
            // leave if at top
            if (parent_index == 0) break;
            
            // find new parent
            last_index = parent_index;
            node_direction = (last_index % 2 == 0) ? IS_RIGHT : IS_LEFT;
            parent_index = (last_index - node_direction) / 2;
        }
    }
    
    
    
    // remove any node
    void remove(int val)
    {
        
        size_t parent_index{ };
        auto search = hashmap.find(val);
        if (search != hashmap.end())
        {
            parent_index = hashmap[val].back();
            hashmap[val].pop_back();
            if (hashmap[val].size() == 0) hashmap.erase(val);
            
        } else return;
        
        
        last_index = heap.size()-1;
        heap[parent_index] = heap[last_index];
        heap.pop_back();

        size_t left_child = (parent_index * 2) + 1;
        size_t right_child = (parent_index * 2) + 2;
        
        size_t smallest_child{ };


        if (left_child > last_index) return;
        
        if (left_child == last_index && heap[left_child] > heap[parent_index]) return;
        
        if (right_child > last_index)
            smallest_child = left_child;
        else
            smallest_child = (heap[left_child] < heap[right_child]) ? left_child : right_child;

        while (heap[parent_index] > heap[smallest_child])
        {
            swapVectorValue(hashmap[heap[parent_index]], parent_index, hashmap[heap[smallest_child]], smallest_child);

            // update value of parent and new node
            int temp { heap[parent_index] };
            heap[parent_index] = heap[smallest_child];
            heap[smallest_child] = temp;
            
            parent_index = smallest_child;
            
            left_child = (parent_index * 2) + 1;
            right_child = (parent_index * 2) + 2;
            
            if (left_child > last_index) return;
            
            if (left_child == last_index && heap[left_child] > heap[parent_index]) return;
            
            if (right_child > last_index)
                smallest_child = left_child;
            else
                smallest_child = (heap[left_child] < heap[right_child]) ? left_child : right_child;
           
        }
    }
    
    
    
    // removes only the top node
    int poll(int val)
    {
        // NOT PROGRAMMED YET
        return 1;
    }
 
    
    
    void display()
    {
        // get parent node
        for (const auto &n: heap)
        {
            std::cout << n << ' ';
        }
        
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    
    


    void hashmapDisplay()
    {
        for (const auto& r: hashmap)
        {
            std::cout << "value: " << r.first << " at indexes: ";
            for (const auto& s: r.second)
            {
                std::cout << s << ' ';
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<BinaryStack> bstack(new BinaryStack());
    bstack->insert(95);

    bstack->insert(9);
    bstack->insert(9);
    bstack->insert(12);
    bstack->insert(14);
    bstack->insert(9);
    bstack->insert(93);
    bstack->remove(93);
    bstack->remove(9);
    
    // proves order of heap
    bstack->display();
    
    // just to prove the indexes are being tracked correctly
    bstack->hashmapDisplay();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, I am sorry to be "that guy" but I think this technically doesn't fit the SO format of a question.

Secondly, if you are looking to implement a priority queue yourself, I recommend you take a look into pointers (and references) in C(++). They are *the* way to implement dynamically allocated tree-like structures. (You'll need to look into memory management and `valgrind` too.)

A fun implementation of priority queue which can be merged and has logarithmic time complexity, including deletion of arbitrary elements is based on [Leftist trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leftist_tree)

Comment: There is no question here. *"just looking to improve"* is a good attitude, but this is not a code review site.